# Wave re-construction - What are my mathematical options

Tags: signal-processing, wavelets

While my question applies to both DSP and Math, I feel it has more depth in mathematics. Here is a sample photo of some samples I have captured over time.

**About the data:**

I have a sensor that monitors pressure. When the pressure increases, the y axis value increases. The opposite is true when the pressure decreases. At times however, if the sensor is bent, it can give odd readings ( samples 210 - 300 below ). Hence, the expansion and contraction of pressure is still recorded, but hidden in the noise generated by bending the sensor.

[image]

I would like to, mathematically, re-construct the middle of the wave ( between samples 210 to 300ish ) , to be more like the clean wave portions ( 50 - 199, 350-450, etc. ), but remain mathematically correct.

**Questions::**

My mathematical background in this is very poor. What are some topics I can visit to try and solve my problem? Surely, my problem here is not by any means new. I am just lacking the correct phrasing to really find the topics myself.

Comment: This question is definitely more appropriate for the [signal processing SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What are you accuracy/fidelity requirements? Is the desired wave a tone or does it have bandwidth? Does this need to be spot on? Or are you looking to just get it done and move on?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I'd like for it to be as accurate as possible. && The tone is never a constant value. i.e The duration of one wave might be different than that of another. ( samples 200 - 100 vs 370 - 430 ) & we'll i'd like to make a very accurate estimation, regardless however long it takes for me to figure it out

Comment: Do you have a model for how bending the sensor affects the measurements?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 the only way I can think of getting this model is by deriving it from the above graph. Not sure how else once could do it, given that no bend is ever going to be the same. i.e different bends with different forces cause more degredation

Comment: If the frequency of the data is constantly changing, you have no model for the error (even a linear distortion of unknown magnitude would be something to start with), and the error can last more than a cycle, I don't have any ideas. Can you limit the change in frequency per unit time? Can you model the bending as a linear/quadratic bias? From the plot you provided, it doesn't look like the signal has much bandwidth. Are there any other stipulations you can set?

Answer (score 2):

The way I would approach that would be through a Fourier series, you are going to have to look into a bit of calculus etc. to do that though.

[Wikipedia - Fourier Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series)

Answer (score 2):

The Fourier transform is not a good choice for wave dynamics insofar as they intrinsically nonlinear. Rather, what you need is a method that embraces the non-linearity. Such a method is the [Hilbert–Huang transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Huang_transform), which was originally developed specifically for the study of wave motion. It's been some years since I've used this but there are various software available. At that time I used programs that were written in Matlab.

Comment: I have posted a follow up question on this link, using your recommendation. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/43043/hht-toning-down-noisy-data Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: @angryip You can see me reply at the signal processing site.